# Is it possible to implement my own conversation scope?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I'm working with Spring-MVC and I need a kind of bean scope like Conversation Scope. I know of Spring Web Flow, but I dislike it because it makes me feel like programming in XML.

So I want to implement my own conversation scope with following functions:

1. Timeout. When a specified time elapses, this cope should be destroyed automatically.
2. I can also destroy this scope manually. Such as calling `myscope.destroy()` method.

How can I implement it?

Comment: And the question is ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta I want to implement a conversational scope by my own

Comment: So you should : first read the relevant part of Spring Reference Manual, and second google on *spring custom scope tutorial*. First answer when I did it was [Custom Scope for Spring Beans](http://www.javabeat.net/custom-scope-spring-beans/) from JavaBeat is seems to be relevant for you question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to implement my own conversation scope?

Answer: yes

It is called a "Custom Scope". Therefore you need to have a class that implements the `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.Scope` Interface

The Spring Reference has a complete chapter about the implementing of an custom scope: [Spring Reference Chapter 4.5.5 Custom scopes](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes-custom)